# C#: finding path to PresentationCore.dll (and other assemblies) in the GAC

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, gac, csharpcodeprovider

I need to reference various assemblies in a `CSharpCodeProvider` via calling `ReferencedAssemblies.Add`.

For some assemblies, it is sufficient to simply pass the assembly name - for example `ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll")`.

However, `PresentationCore.dll` is one of those where a full path to the assembly is required - which I may not necessarily know on the target machine.

### Question:

> How can I locate the definitive path to the (latest?) respective assembly - say, in the GAC?
>
> Ideally, the solution would not only work for `PresentationCore.dll`, but also other assemblies such as `PresentationFramework.dll`, `System.Xaml.dll` or `System.Windows.Forms`.

#### Sources that didn't yield the intended results:

- [This solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fbfdb3bb-e8fe-42af-94a0-9e51176a5b76/csharpcodeprovider-and-wpf?forum=wpf) would involve hard-coding a specific path, but the solution should be dynamic
- Implementing [this Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/fusion/iassemblycache-queryassemblyinfo-method) may work; but I don't know how - or if it would even help solve the above
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891688/linking-to-presentationcore-dll-in-mixed-mode-dll) C++ question refers to where the GAC is found, but not how to get an actual file path

Comment: Is it ok to reference these assemblies in the program that should do the resolving? Then you could just `typeof([TypeKnownToBeInTheDesiredAssembly]).Assembly.CodeBase` and handle the result using: https://stackoverflow.com/a/283917/4035472.

Comment: @thehennyy This worked flawlessly - thanks a lot.  If you could turn this into an answer, I will be able to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference the assemblies in the code that should do the resolving. Then the runtime will tell you the assembly location:

`typeof([TypeKnownToBeInTheDesiredAssembly]).Assembly.CodeBase`

for example, to find the System.Xml.dll:

```
string codeBase = typeof(System.Xml.XmlDocument).Assembly.CodeBase;
UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
Console.WriteLine(path);
```

[[ref]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/283917/4035472)

On my system:

> C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll

Comment: Isn't `Assembly.Location` a better option than `Assembly.CodeBase`?

Comment: `Assembly.Location` is a good point, but I trouble with it in the past. Maybe take both properties into consideration